# Error when converting PyTorch model to TorchScript

Tags: pytorch, torchscript

I'm trying to follow the [PyTorch guide to load models in C++](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/advanced/cpp_export.html).

The following sample code works:

```
import torch
import torchvision

# An instance of your model.
model = torchvision.models.resnet18()

# An example input you would normally provide to your model's forward() method.
example = torch.rand(1, 3, 224, 224)

# Use torch.jit.trace to generate a torch.jit.ScriptModule via tracing.
traced_script_module = torch.jit.trace(model, example)
```

However, when trying other networks, such as squeezenet (or alexnet), my code fails:

```
sq = torchvision.models.squeezenet1_0(pretrained=True)
traced_script_module = torch.jit.trace(sq, example) 

>> traced_script_module = torch.jit.trace(sq, example)                                      
/home/fabio/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/jit/__init__.py:642: TracerWarning: Output nr 1. of the traced function does not match the corresponding output of the Python function.
 Detailed error:
Not within tolerance rtol=1e-05 atol=1e-05 at input[0, 785] (3.1476082801818848 vs. 3.945478677749634) and 999 other locations (100.00%)
  _check_trace([example_inputs], func, executor_options, module, check_tolerance, _force_outplace)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just figured out that models loaded from `torchvision.models` are in train mode by default. AlexNet and SqueezeNet both have Dropout layers, making the inference nondeterministic if in train mode. Simply changing to eval mode fixed the issue:

```
sq = torchvision.models.squeezenet1_0(pretrained=True)
sq.eval()
traced_script_module = torch.jit.trace(sq, example)
```